# Moment Generating Function of a Function of standard normal

Tags: statistics

The problem is this, let $X$, $Y$ be iid rv's with common standard normal density. Let $U=X+Y$ and $V=X^2 + Y^2$. Find the mgf of the random variable $(U,V)$.

Will it be correct if I will get the joint density of $U$ and $V$ using Jacobian transformation then proceed in generating the moment generating function?

Comment: This would be correct but probably not the most efficient approach. Rather, use $$E(e^{uU+vV})=E(e^{uX+vX^2+uY+vY^2})=E(e^{uX+vX^2})^2,$$ and compute $E(e^{uX+vX^2})$ using the PDF of $X$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand your point. How will I be able to compute this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand what you cannot understand in my comment. Would you have problems computing $E(e^{uX+vX^2})$?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, computing it using PDF of X.

Comment: Well, *by definition*, this is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}e^{ux+vx^2}dx,$$ right?

Comment: ok I got it. thank you so much. Can you explain further how did you come up with this expression?E(e^{uU+vV})=E(e^{uX+vX^2+uY+vY^2})=E(e^{uX+vX^2})^2, since I am more aware with Jacobian transformation. Thanks.

Comment: Simply, $e^{uX+vX^2}$ and $e^{uY+vY^2}$ are independent hence $E(e^{uX+vX^2+uY+vY^2})=E(e^{uX+vX^2})E(e^{uY+vY^2})$.

Comment: Ok, I will compute it and get back with you with my answer to check if I did it right. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello, just to clarify, why is the expression E(euX+vX2)2 is squared but in the integrated expression it is not?

Comment: Hello, just to clarify, I suggest to read *carefully* and *slowly* the comments above, the answer to your query is in there.

Comment: Thanks. I got this expression $\rho= \frac{E[(X+Y-E[X]-E[Y])(X^2+Y^2-E[X^2]-E[Y^2])]}{\sqrt{E[(X+Y)^2]-(E[X+Y])^2} \sqrt{E[(X^2+Y^2)^2]-(E[X^2+Y^2])^2}}$ in getting the correlation between $U$ and $V$ where $U=X+Y$ and $V=X^2+Y^2$. How can I simplify it?

Comment: Why start on computing the correlation?

Comment: This is a different question. I posted another one for this topic. Thanks for your support.